# Is there a way to calculate RMS value continuously?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, optimization, continuity

Using that the RMS by definition is:

$\sqrt {\int_0^T\frac 1T*f(t)^2dt} $

which can be calculated by using Riemann sums in the following way:

$\sqrt {\frac 1N\sum_0^Nf[i]^2} $

I've tried that in matlab to use:

```
t=0:0.0001:1
v=230*sin(2*pi*f*t)
v_sq=v.^2
[~,N]=size(v)
sqrt(sum(v_sq))/sqrt(N)
```

but the result is 162.5533, which is not very far from the real 162.6346 and identical with the result from the matlab function rms(v).

The problem is that the size of the data needed to be stored is N=1001 in this case that that will be resource consuming. In other words:

```
t=0:0.0001:0.01
v=230*sin(2*pi*f*t)
v_sq=v.^2
[~,N]=size(v)
sqrt(sum(v_sq))/sqrt(N)
```

I'm still getting half of the wave, but of course the calculated rms=151.5812 is this time far enough from the reality.

So I'm thinking about three possibilities:

1. Reconstruct the sinuous from several samples
2. Calculate the rms continuously with recursive formula
3. Something that I don't know

Of course the best thing would be number 2, but due to luck of time I have to skip the MIT online course of series and I have no idea how the come to such formula if there is any. Therefore any help or comments are welcome.

Comment: Why not just do a loop of additions instead of storing thousands of points? But anyway, 1001 point doesn't require more than several tens of kilobytes of memory — that's not very resource-consuming unless you're on an embedded system.

Comment: @Ruslan those points are presumably already stored, and yes that's exactly the case - I have embedded system with about 128 KB sram, but the real problem is not the memory in this case, but more like the processing time.

Comment: And also the accuracy. For example what will happen when N is very large and can't be stored by a 32-bit integer value. Then I have to set N to zero and how should I preserve the rms already calculated? The best will be something like moving average or I don't know may be there is something better.

Comment: Well, if 1001 points already have a problem in processing time, then $2^{32}\approx 4\,\mathrm{billion}$ would have much larger problem (four million times larger).

Comment: Your question is still unclear: what do you have on input? What constraints do you have? How is the result of the computation to be used and in what mode?

Comment: @Ruslan I assumed that the elements are added in a sum till a counter reaches N. I have on the input the sampled data of the sinusoidal signal I want on the output the rms value, the only constrain is accuracy 0.1% as efficient as possible with respect to the memory, processing time and sampling time. It should work continuously in time i.e. always online.

Comment: So the data is a narrow-spectrum signal? Then indeed, it'd be the best idea to just sample it and reconstruct the waveform (just keep Nyquist theorem in mind), from which RMS would be easy to calculate analytically.

Comment: But how to reconstruct a sinosuid? I know only about reconstruction of polynomials? And I think this will be really prone to noise errors.

Comment: Is expected frequency known well?